# search data from ad in multiple domain

Tags: powershell

I have an existing script which will search data from different domain separately.Please help me to search data from different domain in one shot.

script im using :

```
    Get-ADUser -Server "domainA" -Filter {samaccountname -like "xyaxsdf"} -Properties 
    samaccountname,EmailAddress
```

Comment: Best thing to do is target a global catalog.  `Get-ADUser -Server domainA:3268 -Filter "samaccountname -like 'xyaxsdf'" -Properties samaccountname,EmailAddress`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something as simple as this.

Just set your domains in `$Domains` then a `Foreach` loop will do the query for each domain. Result as you can see is stored in the `$Output` variable, which will contains the results of all your queries

```
$Domains = @('DomainA', 'DomainB')

$Output = Foreach ($Dom in $Domains) {
    Get-ADUser -Server $Dom -Filter { samaccountname -like "xyaxsdf" } -Properties samaccountname, EmailAddress
}
```